# dotnet publish -c Release still produces debug symbols. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using the DEBUG constant in an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application to toggle various features when not in debug mode.  However, when I publish the app using dotnet publish in release mode, it appears as though the DEBUG constant is still defined.

Here's my debug project configuration:

[image: debug configuration]

Here's my release config:

[image: release configuration]

And lastly, my conditional logging code:

[image: conditional code]

When I run

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release
```

And then try to run my code with kestrel using

```
dotnet run kestrel
```

I get the debug warning present in my code along with the notification

```
Hosting environment: Production
```

How can I get the DEBUG constant to not be defined when I build and deploy!?  Thanks a bunch for any help.

Comment: Any strange things when looking at the contents of the .proj files?

Comment: Not sure about `dotnet run kestrel` (Never seen that before and it's not documented.), but `dotnet run` starts a *project*, not a published site, and will default to `Development` environment and `Debug` config. After publishing, you should just be running `dotnet MyApp.dll`.

Comment: Doing a dotnet MyApp.dll seems to indeed run it in release mode.  I took the dotnet run kestrel from a CI/CD script that someone else wrote for the project.  Maybe the kestrel thing is just for debugging and not meant for production.  Regardless thanks for the tip.  If you write a reply, I'll mark it as answered.